# Read NACHA Formatted File using ChoETL DLL Not Working in SSIS package

Tags: choetl

1. I have Used ChoETL.dll and ChoETL.NACHA.dll to read NACHA Formatted file VS2015 C# console and it is working fine.
2. Created an exe for this console application.
3. Called the EXE in SSIS package using "Execute Process Task". But it is throwing the below Error.

```html
Message :Failed to parse line to 'ChoETL.NACHA.ChoNACHABatchHeaderRecord' object.
Filename :Sample.txt
StackTrace :   at ChoETL.ChoManifoldRecordReader.LoadLine(Tuple`2 pair, Object& rec)
   at ChoETL.ChoManifoldRecordReader.<AsEnumerable>d__10.MoveNext()
   at ChoETL.ChoManifoldReader.Read()
   at ChoETL.NACHA.ChoNACHAReader.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at ChoETL.NACHA.ChoNACHAReader.ChoNACHAEnumeratorWrapper.ChoEnumeratorWrapperInternal`1.MoveNext()
   at ChoETL.NACHA.ChoNACHAReader.ChoNACHAEnumeratorWrapper.<BuildEnumerable>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at NachaReader.Program.Main(String[] args
```

Can any one provide solution to resolve this issue. or suggest any other way to Read NACHA formatted file in SSIS package.

Comment: Same sample.txt file works in console app?

Comment: try with absolute data file path and see if works.